# Run a command before running wine in a desktop entry

Tags: desktop, wine

I have this Desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Client PRONOTE 2023
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/path/to/.mysoftware" wine C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Start\\ Menu\\\\Programs\\\\mysoft.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/path/to/Client
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
StartupWMClass=client software.exe
```

It is working fine. But, I would like to run a command before launching this app: `rm -r /path/to/.mysoftware/drive_c/ProgramData/Software/Cache`.

I thought about doing this:
`Exec=rm -r /path/to/.mysoftware/drive_c/ProgramData/Software/Cache ; env WINEPREFIX="/path/to/.mysoftware" wine C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Start\\ Menu\\\\Programs\\\\mysoft.lnk` But that doesn't work.